# Silex optional parameter for all urls

Tags: php, symfony, silex

my question is quite simple, but I could not find an answer on google.

In my silex project I have a parameter that can be or not on my url, e.g.:

```
domain.com/?foo=1
```

When I use the method before it works fine:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app) {
 echo $app['request']->get('foo');
});
```

however if I have any variant of that url I can't catch it anymore. e.g.:

```
domain.com/contact?foo=1
domain.com/about?foo=1
domain.com/company?foo=1
```

...

I know, I could create a route for that.. But if I have 20, 30 different routers, it sounds insane for me change all of them.

Any help would be really appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In the end the problem was in my NGINX. I changed this line

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
```

To

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

Sorry all for this dummy question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the parameters normally like so:

```
$app->get(
    '/contact',
   function () use ($app) {
       exit('foo: ' . $app['request']->get('foo'));
   }
);
```